# Access restricted to the Workfront API - unable to login via StreamClient

Tags: attask, workfront-api

All of a sudden I can no longer login to WorkFront via StreamClient.php.

I was running queries into the database as my access seemed to be being restricted.

What would constitute a reason to remove my companies access to the API via PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Workfront recently disabled TLS authentication - could your applet be using that for https auth?

Rate limiting does sometimes apply for extremely excessive queries, but I've run thousands per hour without any issues. If you are being rate limited, the error message that you receive will clearly indicate that is the cause (I don't have the wording in front of me). What does the raw HTTP error show?

There is also a dedicated API server (api-clxx.my.workfront.com where xx is your cluster number 01-06) that has higher limits and is more responsive. Contact your account rep for more details.